# Can I pass username and password directly in form-data in Postman? or Is it necessary to create HTML form first?

Tags: rest, api, web-services, postman, form-data

I want to send the username and password directly into the Form-data of Postman. I didn't want to create any html form. Is it possible to send credentials without the use of HTML form. Or do I have to create the HTML form? Please advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an HTML form. Postman will take care of it all for you. Here's the [detailed Postman documentation for sending API requests](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/requests) that would help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem corectly:

You don't send anything into postman. You send request from postman to your server and get server's answer. You don't use JAVA to send request. Just define correct url, define all required fields:

- in body's form-data
- or in params

depending on how your serwer works

and hit send button.

Answer (score 0):

This is my resources file

```
package com.demo.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("user")
public class UserResources {

UserDao dao=new UserDao();

@Path("verify")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response verify(@FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("password") 
String password) {

    Response res=new Response();
    userBean bean=dao.verify(username, password);
    if(bean.getUsername()==null) {
        res.setMessage("Username or password is incorrect");
        res.setStatus(false);
        return res;
    }
    else {
        res.setStatus(true);
        res.setMessage("You are logged in successfully");
        bean.getUsername();
        bean.getPassword();
        return res;
    }
}
}
```

And This is my Dao file

```
package com.demo.rest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class UserDao {

public userBean verify(String username, String password) {

    userBean bean=new userBean();

    try {
        Connection con=DB.getCon();
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from voterInfo where 
                username=? AND password=?");

        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, password);

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            bean.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            bean.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        }
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return bean;
    }
}
```

When I pass the Username and Password from form-data in Body of Postman, it is showing my unsupported content type error. I even set the content type to multipart/formdata in header of postman.

Do you think that there is problem with my code? @gregPi